# Git commit -i HEAD not saving contributor

Tags: git

When squashing commit with git rebase -i HEAD~x (x amount of commits) The first squash works fine, saves contributors where necessary, however when squashing again results overwriting the commit owner. Example - 2 commits one by person A, second by person B, after the first squash it will show the files of person A and person B. After person B added another commit and squashed again, the changes of person A will show as done by person B.

P.s.
This could just be avoided by squashing at the very end but I tend to make changes + pull-requests can cause changes.

Expected result:
Keep contributor where they made their changes.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you squash 2 commits from 2 authors, then you can only have a single author (a Git commit can only ever store a single author; there's only a single field in the commit data structure). What are your expectations?

Comment: 2 commits in 2 files respectively. Not sure actually maybe it's our companies specific git feature. Basically 2 commits one in file A done by John, second in file B done by Katie. When squashing only once I can see what is done in file A by John and in file B by Katie. When John decides to add changes in file C and squashes again, the changes in file B done by Katie show as done by John.

Comment: When John squashes, then John creates the squash commit. There is only one author and one committer for a single commit. It is not possible to have two authors for a commit. "When squashing only once I can see what is done in file A by John and in file B by Katie." ← that's impossible. (The only thing I can think of is: John is the committer, Katie is the author). Also, it is misleading and confusing to say "there was 1 commit in 1 file"; it is the other way round: files are part of commits

Comment: If you want to keep the author of each change then you should reconsider the squash approach.

Comment: Even if Git were able to store multiple authors for a single commit: you wouldn't know which author touched which files – this relationship is simply not captured.

Comment: If you don't think that my answer is the correct one to your question, then please [edit] your question to include a [mre] and show (with the proper commands) why you think that Git kept track of multiple authors in a single commit.

Answer (score 2):

Git commits can only store a *single* author and a *single* committer. Often, they are the same person, but when cherry-picking, rebasing (e.g. squashing), or amending commits of somebody else, the committer will be overwritten with your information.

The only way to convey information about authorship by multiple authors is to append a [trailers line](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers), e.g. `Co-authored-by: ...` or `Helped-by: ...`. As far as I know, there does not exist a standardized list of trailer tokens, but the most common one seems to be `Signed-off-by`.

Here's short example showing that only a single author can be stored in a commit:

```
$  g config user.name John
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master #)
$  g config user.email john@example.com
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master #)
$  touch file1
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master #%)
$  git add file1
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master +)
$  git commit -m 'initial commit (authored by john)'
[master (root-commit) 9c7cabf] initial commit (authored by john)
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master)
$  git config user.name Katie
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master)
$  git config user.email katie@example.com
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master)
$  touch file2
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master %)
$  git add file2
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master +)
$  git log -p --format=fuller 9c7cabffc75af6ce6c84c89c9d5835e41d16e4fb
commit 9c7cabffc75af6ce6c84c89c9d5835e41d16e4fb
Author:     John <john@example.com>
AuthorDate: Mon Aug 14 10:04:54 2023 +0200
Commit:     John <john@example.com>
CommitDate: Mon Aug 14 10:04:54 2023 +0200

    initial commit (authored by john)

diff --git a/file1 b/file1
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master +)
$  git commit --amend -m 'initial commit (amended by katie)'
[master fc02380] initial commit (amended by katie)
 Author: John <john@example.com>
 Date: Mon Aug 14 10:04:54 2023 +0200
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1
 create mode 100644 file2
dkf@DT-CGCFHR3:~/test/git/authorship (master)
$  git log -p --format=fuller
commit fc02380febcf27a5e71b3227b00675cc5c988d60 (HEAD -> master)
Author:     John <john@example.com>
AuthorDate: Mon Aug 14 10:04:54 2023 +0200
Commit:     Katie <katie@example.com>
CommitDate: Mon Aug 14 10:05:59 2023 +0200

    initial commit (amended by katie)

diff --git a/file1 b/file1
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/file2 b/file2
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

As you can see, the commit only has a single `Author:` line and a single `Committer:` line.